# Sometimes empty cursor on SQLite query android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

We've been setting up an android application and run into a weird bug when using SQLite where the same query sometimes delivers a result and sometimes doesn't.

When running the below code it might return the requested row, or cursor.moveToFirst might return false. resulting in returning a null.

I've been unable to figure out why `cursor.moveToFirst()` might be failing. The code is running the same statement, with the name being the same on the same database.
The weird thing being it almost seems to alternate betweeen giving the requested row and giving nothing. 
This method is being called from an ASyncTask so there might be multiple calls in succession, but with the task being fired from a button it is unlikely to be called twice at the same time.

Minimum android api level is 8

The connectionInfo object is a wrapper for the information returned.
The connectionName is the name associated with the row being retrieved currently always "default".
The object databaseHelper is an extension of the SQLiteOpenHelper class.
The readFromCursor function reads the item from the cursor, and works properly, the problem being that its not called when the `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false.

```
public ConnectionInfo getConnectionByName(String connectionName) {
    ConnectionInfo info = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(STMT_SELECT_BY_NAME , new String[]{connectionName});

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             info = readFromCursor(cursor);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }       

    DBRefcounter.closeDB(db);   

    return info;
}
```

Called from:

```
public ConnectionInfo createConnectionInfo(String connectionName, String siteURL, String subsite, String username, String password){


    ConnectionInfo info = getConnectionByName(connectionName);      

    if(info == null){
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();     

        values.put(COLUMN_CONNECTION_NAME, connectionName);
        values.put(COLUMN_SERVER_URL, siteURL);
        values.put(COLUMN_SUBSITE, subsite);
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, password);
        values.put(COLUMN_LAST_ACCESS_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());            

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_CONNECTION, null, values);

        DBRefcounter.closeDB(db);//clalls db.close and lowers counter   

        if(id >= 0){

            //Build object to return
        }
    }
    else{
        //update the existing object
    }   

    return info;
}
```

Update:

Can anyone tell me the difference between the .close() and releaseReference methods? according to the api they should be the same but they display different behaviour.

Comment: Put the check like this: `if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){}`

Comment: There really isn't enough information to answer. Chances are that either the data changed or the query changed (e.g. the `connectionName`) param.

Comment: the cursor object is never null, an exception is never thrown, which is what bothers me most.
The connectionName parameter is always "default" in the current testcase.

If you are missing any information, please tell us so we can try and provide it.

Comment: Was this problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

This might be the explanation:

Successive calls fail because you do not terminate the first call appropriately:

1. Before the return, you need to call db.close and cusrsor.close().  db.close is more essential.
2. Not doing this causes an error on the 2nd call, which causes the cursor to be null. This exception closes the db intrinsically. Therefore the 3rd call results in success.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem out of hand. 
It does sound as a plausible source of the error however, we will have a closer look at this, thank you.

Comment: Added a reference counter to the DB creation statement, all references seem to be cleaned up properly but the problem still exists

Comment: from where do you make this call : getConnectionByName(String connectionName)

Comment: remove try-catch block and finally block.
they are useless and a hindrance to trace the error

Comment: Added the calling function and removed the try/catch from the question

Comment: If causing an error would make the next run work again, calling the same function twice should resolve the issue. This doesnt seem to work so I'm affraid your suggested issue isnt the case for us

Answer (score 0):

it happens also because of the leak,
this code stops the leak and fixes cursor problems.

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
    
      private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;
    
      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
      private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table_name";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    
      public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    
        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
        // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
        if (sInstance == null) {
          sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
      }
    
      /**
       * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
       * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
       */
      private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }
    }
```